# EF for Top 10 most popular locations c#

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql

I have a table tbLocations with the following columns:

```
int           id      {PRIMARY_KEY, AUTO_INCREMENT}
int           userid  {Foreign key with table_users}
varchar(200)  location
```

In this table I have the following rows:

```
1, 1, New York
2, 1, California
3, 1, Seattle
4, 1, New York
5, 2, Seattle
6, 2, Ontario
7, 3, Chicago
8, 4, Las Vegas
9, 5, New York
```

I want to create a c# linq query that gets me the top 10 locations, in my case I should get

```
New York  2
Seattle   2
```

The issue here is that a location can be duplicate for a user `i.e. New York is duplicate for userid 1` so I don't want such duplication to affect the final report.

Like in the final report I have New York =2 and not =3

How can I do this in LINQ?

I really have no idea where to start, I tried by grouping by but that didn't work

Comment: *I tried by grouping by but that didn't work* - it's not a problem description. Provide your code, describe the problem you have with your code.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy that was tsql code and the results wasn't really close to what I am trying to acheive. I guess I am more lost on how to approach this. even with TSQL logic I can't seem to get a head start on it

Comment: I think you just want to select distinct in entity framework?

Comment: Ibrahim, I try to reproduce your problem, I will give you the solution. By the way you must fix the primary key of row 5, it is duplicate!

Comment: @cnom oh thanks, I will do that

Comment: Ok I gave you an answer, it is not in linq, but you can easily make it such. If you need further help, do ask, I just have to be out for an hour or so. Please accept my answer if this helped you!

Comment: @cnom yes I am testing it now will accept right away once I finish test. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [my solution](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YwKdkQ):

```
var locations = new List<Location>
{
    new Location{ Id = 1, UserId = 1, Name = "New York" },
    new Location{ Id = 2, UserId = 1, Name = "California" },
    new Location{ Id = 3, UserId = 1, Name = "Seattle" },
    new Location{ Id = 4, UserId = 1, Name = "New York" },
    new Location{ Id = 5, UserId = 2, Name = "Seattle" },
    new Location{ Id = 6, UserId = 2, Name = "Ontario" },
    new Location{ Id = 7, UserId = 3, Name = "Chicago" },
    new Location{ Id = 8, UserId = 4, Name = "Las Vegas" },
    new Location{ Id = 9, UserId = 5, Name = "New York" },
};

var topLocations = locations
    .GroupBy(location => new { location.UserId, location.Name })
    .Select(group => group.First())
    .GroupBy(location => location.Name)
    .Select(group => new { group.Key, Count = group.Count() })
    .OrderByDescending(location => location.Count)
    .Take(2);

foreach (var item in topLocations)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key} {item.Count}");
}
```

Comment: @IbrahimD.: Glad I could help. And for the future, maybe try to provide the skeleton like I did in my fiddle link. That would help a lot. :-)

Comment: ahh good to know, will do that :)

Answer (score 2):

Start with this query:

```
select top 10 count(*) cnt, [location] from 
     (
     select count(*) as dupl, userid, [location]
     from tbLocations
     group by userid,  [location]
     ) as test
 group by [location]
 order by cnt desc
```

This gives these results:

```
cnt location
2   New York
2   Seattle
1   Ontario
1   California
1   Chicago
1   Las Vegas
```

Comment: Thank you cnom it works like a charm!!!! You are the man! I wish I can accept both your answer and Oliver's, but Oliver's answer is in Linq so I will have to accept that. but thanks again!

Comment: Thank you too Ibrahim! No problem at all, Oliver provider a more precise answer after all!